# Reset prefab to initial state onclick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I reset a prefab in Unity to it's initial state when I click a button?

Absolute beginner, not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to store the actual state data somewhere and reset it manually. Unless you want an editor tool but I am assuming this is in-game during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As TEEQNE said, you'll have to *cache* (save) the values when you start the game (on the `void Start(){}` method probably), then whenever you press the button (on the button's.onClick method) you'll want to reset those values.

Another strategy which could save you from the potentially tedious work of caching each value you want reset, would be to simply destroy the gameobject and reinstantiate it using the prefab.

```
void OnReset(){
  var resetGameobject = Gameobject.Instantiate(myPrefab);
  Destroy(this);
}
```

If you're resetting a lot then you might run into some performance issues with the second approach, but it probably won't be a concern in your case.

Let me know if you need a more detailed walkthrough/code examples.

Answer (score -1):

Probably the simplest way would be to destroy this object and instantiate a new one from this prefab.

You could create some sort of ButtonManager script which holds the reference to the currently active object and when the button is clicked, it destroys it and creates a new one in its place, like this:

```cs
class ButtonManager: MonoBehaviour
{
    // you can drag the prefab in the inspector to this field
    public GameObject prefab;
    
    GameObject actObject;


    // you set this method to be launched in the button's menu
    void OnClick()
    {
        Destroy(actObject);
        actObject = Instantiate(prefab);
    }
}
```

Another way (better optimized and preferable in production and bigger games) would be to just write some sort of Reset function that reverts all the changes made to this object.